# alter query for content listing page in admin

Tags: nodes, users

I want to alter query for "admin/content/" listing page for my specific role i.e. admin_country.

when any one login to the site with above role than it will display those node listing which is related to that country (for managing country I have used one field in my custom content type i.e. restaurant).

also this user can perform all operation except delete any restaurant. this user has no rights to delete any type on content/restaurant.

Thanks,

Comment: See [hook_query_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7). I know documentation is dry as a sand and abundant like water on a desert, but at least it'll help you to know what you want to know ;)

Comment: Wouldn't views bulk operations be better to provide a custom page that does all of the above?

Comment: I have tried with views bulk operations(VBO) but no luck